# OptimisticLockException on entityManager.flush()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

```
ERROR Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) 
 javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : 
         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.wrapStaleStateException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:223)
         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:93)
         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
         at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1395)
         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1378)
         at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor716.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
         at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy213.flush(Unknown Source)
         at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor716.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308)
         at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy213.flush(Unknown Source)
```

This is coming up when I try to save the object from UI the second time from the same application where I did a save first time (first time it does not throw this exception). This error does not go away until I restart my server. If I run my server on another machine this error does not come. So I am wondering if the problem is how db is setup on this machine but not exactly sure.

Looked at the logs and hibernate documentaion, also went through old stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Check the data you are modifying - does it have a version field with optimistic locking enabled? If so, that is to prevent overwrites from other servers with stale data. You'll have to look into how your server are handling reading in the data after changes are made and then merging it into the persistence unit to solve your issue - but this error is by design and meant to tell you to re-read the data and try your changes again.